# Node.js POST does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, curl, express

I am currently trying to learn how to use the MEAN stack and I'm having trouble with executing POST requests on the server.

This is my server.js script.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        {
            username: 'dickeyxxx',
            body: 'node rocks!'
        }
    ]);
});

app.post('api/posts', function(req, res) {
    console.log('post received!');
    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.body);
    res.send(201);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server listening on", 3000);
});
```

I tried sending request to the server using curl. GET requests work without a hitch but POST requests are giving me much trouble. This is my curl statement:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST --data "{\"username\":\"dickeyxxx\",\"body\":\"node rules!\"}" http://localhost:3000/api/posts
```

I'm getting HTTP 404 Not Found and CANNOT POST /api/posts

I've tried restarting my server.js script but to no avail.

How do I solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing forward slash at the beginning for POST. Try

```
app.post('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
res.send(201); 
});
```

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan I'm glad I could help.